# Compilation error: `Class' does not name a type

Tags: c++, class, compilation

I have a pretty simple class called simulator in simulator.h

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Class Simulator {

   private:  
    short int startFloor;  
    short int destFloor;  
   public:  
        void setFloors();  
        void getFloors(short int &, short int &);  

};
```

Now when I compile it, I get this error:
simulator.h:4: error: `Class' does not name a type

What have I got wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

You need to make `Class` lowercase (and should probably stop using the deprecated `iostream.h` header):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Simulator {
    // Stuff here
}
```

Comment: Might as well use `<cstdlib>` too.

Comment: `<iostream.h>` isn't deprecated. It was never a part of the Standard.

Comment: @Prasoon - Which is why I would (and others I know) consider it deprecated (something doesn't have to be standard to be deprecated). There is a standards compliant version that should be used instead.

Comment: Even I had the same doubt once. Read Alf Steinbach's reply [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_thread/thread/e4d5a24bd0812184/98b5f9b3266878e7#98b5f9b3266878e7)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's lowercase class.

Answer (score 1):

should be lowercase "class" instead of "Class" ;)

Answer (score 1):

It must be lower case `class`.

It must be

```
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
Class Simulator {
```

the compiler thinks 'Class' is a type like int, float or a user-defined class, struct or typedef.

The keyword used to define classes in c++ (as other answers also mention) is 'class'.
Note also, the new header file names are iostream (since its a standard c++ header), and cstdlib (since its actually a c header).

Hence it should be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Simulator {

   private:  
    short int startFloor;  
    short int destFloor;  
   public:  
        void setFloors();  
        void getFloors(short int &, short int &);  

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the 'C' a 'c' in the word Class.  Has to be lower case.

Comment: That was right. Of all the syntax errors, I made one  with a typo :(